# How to print absolute paths with git grep

Tags: git, grep

I use the following grepcode command to recursively search a large number of git repositories. It prints the path of found files relative to the repository root, how can I print the absolute path of the file rather than repository relative path.

`grepcode() { 
  find . -type d -name .git | 
  parallel 
    "cd {.} && 
     git grep --color -I --full-name -i '$@' }`

Comment: **A suggestion:** Try removing the `--full-name` option because it makes git-grep consider the project path as its root path. You may need to pass an absolute path to git-grep for it to be able to output that absolute path. So, try to get the absolute path first, combine it with your current relative path (`pwd`), then combine with the `find` result. For getting the absolute path, try playing around with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798862/what-does-git-rev-parse-do